# error related with v-slot in my IDE, or some other issue

Tags: vue.js, ide, v-slot

[image: v-slot error in my IDE]

I am working in vue.js and placed this syntax all over the place, everything works as expected, but I cannot get rid of this error all over the place (Unrecognized slot name).

I've read in several places that maany people have the same issue but I haven't found an answer.

Do you know a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seems to be an unresolved issue with WebStorm IDE](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52117).  For what it's worth, I've not seen this problem when using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I have to say this situation shows different problem in VSC: [vue/valid-v-slot]
'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier.eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: ah, at least as an eslint warning you can modify it's behavior.  see the [docs](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-v-slot.html#options) that say in your eslint config, set the rule's `allowModifiers` option to true, which should stop the warning

Comment: but what happen in phpStorm?